# SQL SERVER 2014 - SELECT permission was denied on View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I created a view `vw_AnnualSales_2016` on **Database A**, and this view is querying data from multiple tables which are stored in **Database B**.

I've granted user to have read access to `vw_AnnualSales_2016` view. And user received below message from SQL SERVER:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object XXXXX

This is due to user does not has read access to the tables on DB B. If I grant user to has read access to these tables, it will resolved the issue. However I don't want user can direct access to these tables, is there any workaround can be done ?

Comment: You need to use a user that do have access (read) to DB B. I did not  try it yet but something like the following should work in theory select x,y,z from b.[user with read access].[table or view ] where ...

Comment: We don't want the user has read access to DB B hence we create view for this purpose

Comment: It's very strange behaviour, I tryed to repeat your problem and all works fine. Create database A with table1 and table 2, create database B with test_user login and user, create view in Database B as SELECT from table1 and table2, grant SELECT on this view to test_user. Then connect as test_user and execute SELECT * FROM test_view - and all works fine. Could you prepare simple demo to reproduce your poblem?